# Como puedo simplificar esta función en una sola linea

Tags: javascript

La funcion que estoy utilizando utiliza mucho este código... como puedo simplificar esto aun más...

```
if(this.active){
   return true;
}else{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: ¿Algo como `return this.active`;?

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no demuestra un mínimo esfuerzo por resolver el problema presentado

Comment: Hola Kronhyx. Para tener publicaciones de la más alta calidad es importante leer [ask] y [mcve]. ahi se explica que has de mostrar tus intentos e investigaciones realizadas para solucionar el problema. En tu pregunta no aparece lo intentado. Nosotros ayudamos a tus problemas concretos (que es como mejor se aprende) , no a tareas. Un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tu `if` valida `this.active`, puedes retornar directamente eso (`return this.active`), en caso que no sea *booleano* ese dato, puedes cambiar a `return !!this.active`, la doble negación lo convierte en *true* o *false*.

---

### Alternativa

Puedes utilizar el operador ternario `?`, para simplificar un `if`.

Sintaxis:

```
condición ? expr1 : expr2
```

La `expr1` se da cuando es *true* la condición y la `expr2` cuando es *false*.

Ejemplo:

```
this.active ? true : false.
```

Ejemplo de diferentes comparaciones

```js
var uno = {};
uno.checkme = function() {
  if (this.active) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

uno.checkme2 = function() {
  return this.active
}

uno.checkme3 = function() {
  return this.active ? true : false;
}

uno.checkme4 = function() {
  return !!this.active ? true : false;
}

var doCheck = function() {
  console.log(
    uno.checkme(), uno.checkme2(), uno.checkme3(),uno.checkme4()
  );
}
// undefined
doCheck();

// boolean true
uno.active = true;
doCheck();

// string "false"
uno.active = "false";
doCheck();

// string "true"
uno.active = "true";
doCheck();

// string "batata"
uno.active = "batata";
doCheck();
```